# Use Python to read a XML file with duplicated tag name

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I need to read a XML file which including multiple duplicated Tag name `Keyword`,

And here is my example of xmlfile.xml input:

```
<LogPattern>    
    <DefectID>5664</DefectID>   
    <EscalationID>5782</EscalationID>
    <Title>ProcessImageRequests exception in ImageServer</Title>
    
    <KeywordList Type="sequence">       
        <Keyword name="a1" subrelationship="And">
            <Keyword name="a1001" subrelationship="Or">
                <Keyword name="a1001001" Value="Keyword1001001"/>
                <Keyword name="a1001002" subrelationship="Not" value="Keyword1001002"/>
            </Keyword>
            <Keyword name="a1002" LoggerName="Generator" Value="Keyword1002"/>
            <Keyword name="a1003" Value="Keyword1003"/>
            <Keyword name="a1004" Value="Keyword1004"/>
                
            
        </Keyword>
        <Keyword name="a2" Value="Keyword2"/>
        <Keyword name="a3" Value="Keyword3"/>
        <Keyword name="a4" Value="Keyword4"/>
    
    </KeywordList>
</LogPattern>
```

And here is my code for reading xml file and get element with tag name `Keyword`:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xmldom


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml_file = xmldom.parse('xmlfile.xml')
    eles = xml_file.documentElement
    print(eles.tagName)
    defect = eles.getElementsByTagName('DefectID')[0].firstChild.data
    escalation = eles.getElementsByTagName('EscalationID')[0].firstChild.data
    title = eles.getElementsByTagName('Title')[0].firstChild.data
    key = eles.getElementsByTagName('Keyword')
    print(key[0].getAttribute('name'))
```

My method would get all `Keyword` without the relationship.

In the xml file, the `Keyword name="a1"` is the parent which has children `Keyword name="a1001"`, `Keyword name="a1002"`,`Keyword name="a1003"` and `Keyword name="a1004"`.

Is there any method I can determine which `Keyword` is a child of `Keyword name="a1"` without changing the tag name and print it as a dictionary?

Expect Output as dictionary:

```
{'a1':
    {'a1001':
        {'a1001001': 'Keyword1001001'},
        {'a1001002': 'Keyword1001002'}
    }, 
    {'a1002':'Keyword1002'}, 
    {'a1003':'Keyword1003'}, 
    {'a1004':'Keyword1004'}
}
```

Comment: @mzjn Thanks for reminding, question updated.

Answer (score 0):

`xml.dom.minidom` is not suitable for solving this problem, since it immediately takes all, even nested, `Keyword` elements.

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xmldom
from pprint import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dom = xmldom.parse('input.xml')
    keywords = dom.getElementsByTagName("KeywordList")
    keyword = keywords[0].getElementsByTagName("Keyword")
    pprint(keyword)

-----------------------------

[<DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce160>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce1f0>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce280>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce310>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce3a0>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce430>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce4c0>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce550>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce5e0>,
 <DOM Element: Keyword at 0x216a1bce670>]
```

When using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, this task becomes solvable, which is recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom), since you can iterate over each level of tags with the same name.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
    keywords = tree.find('KeywordList')
    for keyword in keywords:
        print(keyword.attrib)

--------------------------------

{'name': 'a1', 'subrelationship': 'And'}
{'name': 'a2', 'Value': 'Keyword2'}
{'name': 'a3', 'Value': 'Keyword3'}
{'name': 'a4', 'Value': 'Keyword4'}
```